# Making a copy of an Opportunity Record in to separate child object

Tags: opportunity

Is it possible to take a "picture" of an Opportunity record with all the fields and write those values into a new record on a child object of the Opportunity (custom object called Opportunity Timeline for example).

The purpose is to be able to take snapshots of the Opportunity over time so you can go back in time and in one report see your timestamp and what the records were at that time?

This would be different than a standard snapshot as it would just be done per record as needed and then written into a child record of the Opportunity.

As a side note, could you schedule it to take a snapshot of all Opportunity records on Sunday at noon (for example)

Thanks!

Comment: why not use analytic snapshot feature (for long term analysis) or historical trend reporting for up to 3 mo reporting?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to either use the snapshots features in Salesforce or to use Field History to accomplish this, but to answer the question, it is possible.

So, the non-recommended solution:

Create a Fieldset on Opportunity with the name of the fields you want to copy over. Standard fields will probably need to be left out because you'll have to make sure the field API names match.

In the after update trigger on Opportunities:

```
// Get the fieldset
Schema.FieldSet fs = Opportunity.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fieldSets.getMap().get('NAME_OF_FIELDSET');
List<Opportunity_History__c> copies = new List<Opportunity_History__c>();
Opportunity_History__c copy;
// Loop through all the newly updated opportunities
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
    // Create the new copy instance
    copy = new Opportunity_History__c(Opportunity__c=opp.Id);
    // Copy any values from standard fields since the field names won't match
    copy.Opp_Name__c = opp.Name;
    // Copy all fields from the set
    for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : fs.getFields()) {
        copy.set(opp.get(fsm.fieldPath));
    }
    copies.add(copy);
}
// insert the copies
insert copies;
```

This is kind of messy and requires maintaining if fields change, so I'd recommend one of the built in solutions before this, but if you need it, this should work.